# How to disable sharing site only and use only group sharing?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-groups, sharing

I have a groupified SharePoint site. At this moment it is possible to share the SharePoint site with 2 ways. "Add members to group" and "Share site only". How to disable "Share site only"? I would like to use only "Add members to group".

[image]

Comment: Can you use PnP PowerShell? `Set-SPOSite -Identity https://domain.sharepoint.com -DisableSharingForNonOwners`
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off